# I can't log out the output C program

Tags: c, allegro, allegro5

I am developping a game with allegro library. I wrote a starter C code then I compile the program on Ubuntu Terminal.After that When I open the output program,the program open but not closed.Cancel Button(X) is not working.

Here is my starter code:

```
#include <allegro.h>

void Baslat();
void Bitir();

int main(){
        Baslat();
        while(!key[KEY_ESC]){

        }
        Bitir();
        return 0;
}

END_OF_MAIN()

void Baslat(){
        int depth,res;
        allegro_init();
        depth = desktop_color_depth();
        if(depth == 0) depth=32;
        set_color_depth(depth);
        res=set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640,480,0,0);
        if(res!=0){
                allegro_message("%s\n", allegro_error);                  exit(-1);
        }
        install_timer();
        install_keyboard();
        install_mouse();

}


void Bitir(){
  clear_keybuf();

}
```

Comment: Tried debugging? Run your app in the debugger and hit Ctrl+C when it hangs on exit.

Comment: I answered for `allegro5` based on the tag, but it looks like you are actually using `allegro4`. Which version of allegro are you interested in?

Answer (score 0):

To respond to a user pressing the `X` button in allegro5, you must catch [`ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE`](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.2.2/events.html#allegro_event_display_close). [This tutorial](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial/Events) provides an example of responding to that event.

Comment: Yes I use allegro4 but I can't understand your answer.
Which allegro release should I use?                                                                   Is there a way for solving my problem at allegro4?

Comment: Which release to use is a personal decision, but I would use the most recent release unless you have a compelling reason to use an old version. I don't use `allegro4` so I don't know how to solve your problem with it. If you are using `allegro5`, the tutorial I linked gives a code sample and explanation for exactly what you want.